# Android update Hashmap is not working

Tags: android, hashmap, updates

In my android application i have used extended listview, to update the parent name and child name with values i have used

```
public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> alertvalues = new LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

this kind of hash map. i can successfully load the data into extended listview but failed to update the value. when i select and unselect the child items need to update the value 0 and 1 respectively. 
my try is below

```
chilitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Integer.parseInt(alertvalues.get(
                    groulist.get(groupPosition)).get(
                    collections.get(groulist.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition))) == 0) {

                alertcheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//here i need to update the value into array but failed to do

                alertvalues.get(groulist.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        collections.get(groulist.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition));

            } else {
                alertcheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }
    });
```

can anyone give tip to update the value

Comment: This clickListener is in your getChildView() method?

Comment: yes yes. I have implemented in getChilview() method